# Can't compile executable from .c file on ntfs formated partition

Tags: c, linux

I've been trying for long time to solve an apparent problem with compiling simple C code into an executable. I've made a simple C code that should print the size in bytes of a `double` to a `.txt` file via makefile. It doesn't compile an executable on my system, but works flawlessly on my university's Linux server. I'm running **Linux Mint 17.1 64bit** with cc version "**cc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2**". My test C-code is in the file *`temp.c`*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("sizeof(double) returns %lu\n", sizeof(double));
    return 0;
}
```

My `makefile` looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -m64 -std=c99

all: A;

A:out.txt

out.txt: temp;
    ./temp > out.txt
    chmod go+r

temp: temp.o

clean:
    rm temp.o
    rm temp out.txt
```

Typing `cc -dumpversion` while logged in on my universitys linux server returns "`cc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)`", and typing "`cc-dumpmachine`" returns "`x86_64-redhat-linux`"

I don't understand why `make all` on my machine returns

```
cc -Wall -m64 -std=c99   -c -o temp.o temp.c
cc   temp.o   -o temp
./temp > out.txt
/bin/sh: 1: ./temp: Permission denied
make: *** [out.txt] Error 126
```

Additional info:
`temp.c` is in a folder on an NTFS partition which is auto mounted at boot with option **exec**. Compiling `temp.c` without `-c` from the shell instead of makefile doesn't do the job. Anytime I try to run `./temp` or whatever the outcome of the compiling returns the "`Permission denied`" statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by the OP in the comments, the executable file is in an NTFS formatted partition. By default, Ubuntu (and hence I would assume Mint) does not mount NTFS in such a way that files can be executed.

Quoting from [an answer on AskUbuntu by @Sebastian](https://askubuntu.com/a/594438/274080) (with modifications), the following change is to be made on `/etc/fstab`:

> The solution was to write the `exec` mount option **after** the `users` option. That's because the `users` option implicitly activate the `noexec` option, so you have to explicitly specify `exec`.